# How to do a complexity analysis using tau-notation of an if statement

Tags: time-complexity

I am currently busy with complexity analysis problems and want to know what the correct method is for analyzing if statements using Tau notation.

Here is an example problem with 2 solutions.

if(x>=y[z])

a. 4τfetch + τ[.] + τ<
b. 5τfetch + τ[.] + τ< + τreturn

Please indicate which solution, a or b, would be correct.
Please explain why the solution is correct.

Please explain why I am wrong if both are wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my reasoning:
`
if(x>=y[z])

_y[z]: 3τfetch + τ[.]
_x: τfetch
_>=: τ<

Therefore:
a.  4τfetch + τ[.] + τ<

---

if(x>=y[z])

_y[z]: 3τfetch + τ[.]
_x: τfetch
_>=: τ<
_if(): τfetch + τreturn

Therefore:
b.  5τfetch + τ[.] + τ< + τreturn

Answer (score 0):

If() isn't a method, so if() shouldn't have a return, thats why you have the τ< because it compares the value to give a true / false value. So according to that "a" should be the correct one.

Edit: The only time you would use the τreturn + τfetch is when you have a method that is returning a value to a variable, such as "x = RandomNum(lower,upper)"

Answer (score 0):

The if() is only a condition and does not return a value. Only when you are returning a value, as Armin mentioned, you will have a τreturn.

Answer (score 0):

If() is only a statement the same way for() is. It does not return a value, but only compares values.

You only have τfetch for the values being compared and τ< for the comparison.

[Here is a photo of page 13 from the book "Data structures and algorithms with object-oriented design patterns in Java" by Preiss with an if statement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqmWM.png) There is no τfetch or τreturn for the if() statement here.

Therefore your answer is a: 4τfetch + τ[.] + τ<